# Reading letters and avoiding numbers and symbols

Tags: java

I am given a .txt file which has a bunch of words, here is a sample of what it looks like:

```
Legs
m%cks
animals
s3nt!m4nts
```

I need to create a code which reads this .txt file and put the words without numbers and symbols into an array. So basically I gotta put Legs and animals into an array The other two words I gotta just print it out.

```
public class Readwords {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array=new string[10];
    }
}
```

How do I get the program to read letters only and ignore the numbers and symbols?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex for finding numbers and symbols,after that replace them.

1).Read the whole `.txt` file to a string.

2).Use `replaceAll` function to replace the unwanted characters.

```
String str = your text;

str = str.replaceAll(your regex, "");
```

Comment: OP does not want to change replace unwanted characters

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
try {
     BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourfile.txt")
     String line;
     ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

     while ((line = file.nextLine()) != null) {
         if (line.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
             array.add(line);
         else
             System.out.println(line);
    }

    String[] result = array.toArray(new String[array.size()]);

    file.close();
    return result;
}
catch (Exception e)
    e.printStackTrace;
```